# insert data from datagridview or datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

Ok, after 2 days I got grid and max id from table working, now new problem:
How to insert all products on the gridview which is also on datatable dtprodisp
I got the first product inserted but don't know to do for loop and not repeat any already inserted product

```
private void Btngravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("ConnectionString");
        
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand objcmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into dispensacao (DESTINATARIO,COD_UNIDADE,COD_DEPARTAMENTO,DATA,SOLICITANTE,DEFERIDO_POR) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DESTINATARIO", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = Cmbdestinatario.Text;
        
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_UNIDADE", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtcodigounidade.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Txtcodigounidade.Text);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_DEPARTAMENTO", string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtcodigodep.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Txtcodigodep.Text);
       
        DateTime fdate = DateTime.Parse(Txtdata.Text);           
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fdate;
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@SOLICITANTE", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtsolicitante.Text;
        objcmd.Parameters.Add("@DEFERIDO_POR", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = Txtdeferido.Text;
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        conn.Open();
       
        objcmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into produtos_disp(CODIGO_DISP,PRODUTO,QUANTIDADE,CODIGO_PROD) values (?,?,?,?)", conn);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO_DISP", Cmbid.Text);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUTIO", dtproddisp.Rows[0]["descricao"]);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTIDADE", dtproddisp.Rows[0]["quantidade"]);
        objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_PRODUTO", dtproddisp.Rows[0]["codigo"]);
        
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       

   

        this.Close();
    }
```

this is the code and it works for the fist row

```
dtproddisp.Rows.Add(Txtcodigopro.Text, Txtproduto.Text, Txtquantidade.Text);
```

Do I need to change that?
the code to add data to dtprodisp DataTable is not geting the codigo for some reason, was working a few minutes ago and i din't change anything:

```
 private void Btnaddproduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dtproddisp.Rows.Add(Txtcodigopro.Text, Txtproduto.Text, Txtquantidade.Text);

        Gridprodutos.DataSource = dtproddisp;

    }
```

both other fields are working
code to get "DESCRICAO" and "CODIGO":

```
private void Txtproduto_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("connectionString");

            string selectQuery = "select descricao,codigo from produtos where barras =" + (Txtproduto.Text);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);               
           
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                Txtproduto.Text = reader.GetString("DESCRICAO");
                Txtcodigopro.Text = reader.GetString("CODIGO");
            }
           
           
        }

    }
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking. If you want to insert all the rows in the data table then a simple `for` or `foreach` loop through the table’s rows would work. In each iteration, clear the previous parameters and re-add the parameters with the values from that particular row. I am guessing this may be what you are asking.

Comment: Is there some reason the `foreach` loop is empty? You could also use a `for` loop as you have done in the previous loop. Both will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: just set there to show what i'n trying

Comment: objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anyText", dtproddisp.Rows['i']['j']); raises an error any ideias

Comment: You need to show the code you are using as the current code will not compile. You will get an error for the line of code at… `foreach ()` … this is invalid and the code will not compile. So I am not sure how you would get an executing error on the line…  `objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@anyText", dtproddisp.Rows['i']['j']);` … I can only guess another compilation error for `i` and `j` since they are out of scope and technically do not exist. Please [edit] your question with your updated code.

Comment: JohnG just edited that's the code working for the first row, i've read for that " for "thing but coun't make it work

Answer (score 0):

After weeks i finally found the way to make it work;

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtproddisp.Rows.Count; i++)

        {
            objcmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into produtos_disp(CODIGO_DISP,PRODUTO,QUANTIDADE,CODIGO_PROD) values (?,?,?,?)", conn);
           
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODIGO_DISP", Cmbid.Text);
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRODUTIO", dtproddisp.Rows[i]["descricao"]);
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUANTIDADE", dtproddisp.Rows[i]["quantidade"]);
            objcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_PRODUTO", dtproddisp.Rows[i]["codigo"]);
            objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

If anyone else has the same problem, I've posted my solution
now i need to polish it, need to get max id from table, for now i i'n using a combobox with desc order to get it, but i believe there're a better way to do it